# image is not getting displayed in div class

Tags: javascript, css

I had an existing code to display the detail information but in this page there is one div class "gallery". In this div class, I have inherited one code inside this div class (gallery) to display the image, but image is not getting displayed. Please help.

Code is pasted here : http://jsfiddle.net/u99bwqh0/2/

**Detail page code (index.html)**

```
<html>
<link href="./css/index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="./css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="./css/style_blue.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<body>
<div class="page centered" style="width: 1200px; min-width: 1200px;">
<div class="main box">
<div class="pdiv2 gdiv">
<div id="ad-details-view" class="views">
<div id="gallery" class="lfloat">

<section id="gallery-con">
    <section id="gallery-main">
        <img src="./images/content/1.jpg" height=400 width=600 />
    </section>
    <section id="gallery-hidden">
        <img src="./images/content/1.jpg"  height=400 width=600/>
        <img src="./images/content/2.jpg" height=400 width=600/>
        <img src="./images/content/3.jpg" height=400 width=600/>
        <img src="./images/content/4.jpg" height=400 width=600/>
        <img src="./images/content/5.jpg" height=400 width=600/>

    </section>
    <section id="thumbnails">
        <div id="playtoggle" class="ui-button"><div class="icon icon-pause"></div></div>
        <div id="left-arrow" class="ui-button"><div class="icon icon-arrow-left"></div></div>
        <div id="thumbcon">

        </div>
        <div id="right-arrow" class="ui-button"><div class="icon icon-arrow-right"></div></div>
    </section>

</section>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script defer src="./js/gallery.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-36251023-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'jqueryscript.net']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
                </div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div></div></div></div>

</body></html>
```

Please find complete package with (css and js) at below path :

http://speedy.sh/sKYGR/WebApplication3.zip

Comment: Please, post your jsfiddle.

Comment: This is fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/. Create your sample so that we can help

Comment: Can you edit your question to add a snippet? (Click the `<>` icon, it will open a small HTML editor.) Also, can you explain which image is not visible? There are six images in the code and none of them is in a container with class "gallery". So, which one's the problem?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/u99bwqh0/

Comment: I have posted my code at above location

Comment: ``<section id="gallery-main">
        <img src="./images/content/1.jpg" height=400 width=600 />
    </section> `` is not getting displayed.

Comment: i recon its your relative pathiing.... see  <img src="./images/content/1.jpg"  height=400 width=600/>..... try replaceing "." with the sites actual relative path or hard code it... until you proven its not that. <img src="./images/content/1.jpg"  height=400 width=600/> is never going to resolve in jsfiddle

Comment: Now see...just updated the jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/u99bwqh0/2/

Comment: OK, what is the `z-index: -1` for?